# codeigniter require no such file or directory

Tags: php, codeigniter, require

I just got a very frustating error. I always use `require 'file_name'` when i tried to load a view (ex : header).

Im using `CI` now and i tried to do something like this : `<?php require 'header_v.php';?>` in my `home_v.php` but it always give me the **No such file or directory** error.

This is `header_v.php` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Backend-Vihara Dharma Bhakti</title>
<link href="../../../style/style_backend.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>style/style_backend.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.css" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });

  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
</script>

<div id="header"><h1>HEADER</h1></div>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="backend/umat">Daftar Umat</a></li>
            <li><a href="backend/pengurus">Daftar Pengurus</a></li>
            <li><a href="backend/absensi">Absensi</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</head>
```

And this is `home_v.php` (the one that require header_v.php) :

```
<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.css" />
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
      });
     </script>

    <?php require 'header_v.php';?>

    <div id="form_search">
        <?php echo form_open('backend/index') ?>
           <p>
               <?php echo form_dropdown('ddl_search', $data_search, 'id="ddl_search"');?>
           </p> 
            <p>
                Kelas :
                <?php echo form_dropdown('ddl_kelas1', $list_kelas, 'id="ddl_kelas1"');?> -
                <?php echo form_dropdown('ddl_kelas2', $list_kelas, 'id="ddl_kelas2"');?>
            </p>
            <p>
                Nama : <?php echo form_input('txt_nama');?>
                Alamat : <?php echo form_input('txt_alamat');?>
                Tanggal Lahir : <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
            </p>
                <?php echo form_submit('btn_search', 'Search');?>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    </div>
    <div>
        <?php echo $table ?>
        <?php echo $pagination ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What am i missing?Does it has something to do with `config.php`, `routes.php` or other CI's settings?Because i have use this way so many time and its always working except now.

Thanks for your help :D

**NOTE** : The file name is right, `header_v` and `home_v` is in the same folder(**views**).

Comment: That doesn't work because you'll be in the root of your app. If you want to include a header like that you have to give to full path from the root of your app. However the framework provides better ways to do that. E.g. `$this->load->view('header')`.

Comment: Thanks for your help :D Its working, i did it in another project...

Comment: Wait, i think its not a duplicate, i am asking about require.

Comment: The other question boils down to the same thing. Difference between require and include is just a detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to load a view file is this:

```
$this->load->view('file-in-views-folder')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :D I tried it and it just gave me a white-blank page, any idea? Thanks :D

Comment: You're using `<?php $this->load->view('header_v'); ?>` in place of `<?php require 'header_v.php';?>`, yes?

Comment: no, i put it in my controller :D

Comment: Can you update your post above with the code from your controller as well?

Comment: @BlazeTama, you should put it in your view.

Answer (score 2):

To use the require function in CI, you have to type the full path of that file.

Like:

```
<?php require '/var/www/main/application/views/header_v.php';?>
```

But, the correct way using CI, is to load the view in your controller.

```
 $this->load->view("header_v");
```

and then

```
 $this->load->view("home_v"); //remove the require function from your code.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :D I tried it and it just gave me a white-blank page, any idea? Thanks :D

Comment: Did you use your own full path, didn't you?

Comment: Can you show the part of your controller file where you invoke those views?

Comment: Also, try to view source code in the blank page. Maybe the page is loading just the header, not the body.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you load in your controller file?

```
$this->load->view('header_v');
$this->load->view('home_v');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :D I tried it and it just gave me a white-blank page, any idea? Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

if you want to output somenthing use

```
echo $this->load->file('/path/to/myfile');
```

if it's a view

```
echo $this->load->view('myviewname');
```

if it's a php library or an helper (so you haven't to output somenthing but just require or include classes and methods):

```
$this->load->helper();
$this->load->library();
```

***Remember***

**views** has to stay under `/application/views` folder

**libraries** under `/application/libraries`

**helpers** under `/application/helpers`

**general files types** can stay where you want since you use to load them with the enteire path to them `/path/to/my/file`